# How to interpret QFT fields (in relation with QM)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, second-quantization, klein-gordon-equation

In [QM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) we deal with the Schrödinger equation:<sup>1</sup>

$$i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi = H \psi$$

the wave function $\psi(x)$ is the main object of interest: it can be interpreted as a scalar field, in the sense that it links every point in space with a scalar value, and the really neat thing is that the scalar value in question is nothing but the probability amplitude of the particle described by $\psi$ being in that position $x$.
This links very neatly with the bra-ket notation: in QM we know that the probability amplitude of a particle in state $|\psi\rangle$ to be measured in state $|\phi\rangle$ is:

$$\langle \phi| \psi \rangle$$

this is nothing but the scalar product of the two kets, as defined in Hilbert space. It's simply an expression of [Born's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule). This fits well with the concept of wave function $\psi (x)$ since we can interpret it as simply an infinite dimensional vector of scalar products:

$$\psi (x)=\begin{pmatrix}\langle x'|\psi\rangle\\\langle x'' | \psi \rangle\\.\\.\\.\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

this last visual really helped me to understand the concept of wave function in relation with bra-ket representation.

Given all this I feel like I know what I am talking about when I speak of quantum states and wave functions, the problem is that this confidence completely breaks switching in the [QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) framework. To expose my doubts let's stick to the Klein-Gordon field, where the problem is more evident.

Trying to marry QM with Special Relativity we can arrive to the [Klein-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation):<sup>2</sup>

$$(\partial ^2 +m^2)\phi(x) =0 \ \ \ , \ \ \ \phi \in \mathbb{R}$$

this equation describes a real scalar field (we could deal with a complex, charged, field, but lets keep this simple).

**Here the problems begin:**

We could try interpreting $\phi$ as a wave function like we did in QM, but the problem is that the scalar product defined on the space of the solutions of the K-G equation *is not positive definite!* So we cannot interpret the scalar product as a probability amplitude, and so we cannot link the field $\phi$ with the bra-ket representation like we did in $(1)$.<sup>3</sup>

Furthermore when we dig a little deeper in the matter we find out that the state of the system now has to be represented in [Fock's space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space), since we are stuck with a formalism that predicts a variable number of particles. So Hilbert space flyes out the window: the kets still represent the quantum state of the system, but now they are vectors in Fock's space, and I can't find a clear link of any kind with the field $\phi$ like we had before in $(1)$.

On top of this when we perform second quantisation, to impose the necessary commutation relations, we start interpreting $\phi (x)$ not as a true scalar field, but as a field of operators (hermitian operators to be precise, since we said $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$). This creates even more confusion since now the field is a field of operators, and linking it with the concept of quantum state, represented by a ket, or to the concept of particle, or probability amplitude, becomes more and more tricky.

**Given this context my question is:**

Is there a neat interpretation of the concept of *field* in QFT (pre or post second quantization), that conceptually links it to quantum ket states in Fock's space, like we had in QM?

---

**[1]:** Allow me to use natural units: $\hbar,c = 1$.

**[2]:** $\partial ^2$ is the [d'Alembert operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator).

**[3]:** I know that this was a problem also for the physicist working on this stuff one hundred years ago, including Dirac himself; he developed his equation trying to takle exactly this problem, but apparently turns out that the problem of positive definitiveness is not a problem at all, and the K-G equation is perfectly usable to describe spinless bosons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between principles of QM and QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/345554/) and links therein

Comment: This is an excellently formed question and I look forward to the answers/discussion

Comment: @TobiasFünke No, it doesn't; my question asks something very specific, and more thecnical: a conceptual and mathematical link between Fock's space state vectors and the QFT/QED fields

Comment: As far as I understand your question, this exactly answers your points. Quantum fields are operator-valued distributions. Elements of the Fock space are...well, elements of the Fock space. You can calculate expectation values of products of quantum fields and so on, in such a state. This is done in any intro QFT book/course.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I have no doubts that this topic has been tackled before in books, but I am having an hard time understanding it. If you could comment in some resources I would be grateful. But at the same time, no, is not the same question as the one you linked; I am only interested about the link between kets and fields. The concept of an elementary field excitation representing a particle must be key here, but I donnow how. Also we cannot interpret the field trough the scalar product since the field is now an operator, right?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/799762/).

Comment: @Noumeno What books have you read?

Comment: I would recommand Duncan's *Conceptual framework of Quantum Field Theory*, which IMO gives some nice answers to this kind of questions